# is SUBEXP contained within PSPACE?, NP?

Tags: time-complexity, np, complexity, pspace

Let SUBEXP is the complexity class of all problems solvable in sub-exponential time in the length of the input. What are the known properties of this class? Is it known to be contained in PSPACE, if so, is it known to be contained in NP? Is it thought to lie outside of PSPACE? My intuition says there should be problems that are Solvable in at least Sub-expoential time and Sub-exponential space, but not be in PSPACE.

Also, if SUBEXP lies outside of NP, and there is a SUBEXP complete problem, wouldn't that disprove ETH?

Comment: P is of course strictly contained in SUBEXP,  and we don't know if P=PSPACE. So a positive response to your first question would imply P≠PSPACE. Same thing for the second question (P≠NP). However, if you assume SETH, then SUBEXP is contained in NP (which is contained in - or equal to - PSPACE)

Comment: @Lamine Even assuming SETH, wouldn't there probably exist problems solvable in  Subexponential time and Subexponential(but superpolynomial) Space? Therefore implying that SUBEXP is not contained in PSPACE? This is just institutional but still, at the very least this is an argument against SETH.

Comment: @Lamine If SUBEXP contains problems outside PSPACE (which we currently cannot rule out I suppose), then SETH doesn't imply anything about those.

Comment: @Hermann Gruber Does SUBEXP being outside PSPACE imply that SETH is false?

Comment: No. I don't see how this could imply anything about the truthiness of (S)ETH...

Comment: There is no SUBEXP-complete problem.

Comment: (But even if there were, I don’t see how this would imply anything about the truth of ETH.)

Comment: @Emil Jerabek, if SUBEXP had complete problems and was outside of PSPACE, that would imply that NP was contained in SUBEXP.

Comment: @Colonizor48 No, it would imply no such thing. I have no idea why you think that.

Answer (score 7):

SUBEXP is neither known or widely believed to lie in PSPACE (and -- contrary to one of the comments -- this is not known to have any connection to SETH).  It is not known whether the containment "SUBEXP in PSPACE" would imply that SUBEXP is in NP; there are oracles relative to which P=NP and PSPACE = EXP, and thus there are oracles relative to which this implication fails.